# git-lfs .gitattributes file: strange unicode characters

Tags: windows, git, git-lfs

I am using git on windows.

I added the following line to `.gitattributes` file:

```
"*.msi" filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Then I checked with `git lfs track` but nothing shows up.

Then I tried adding with `git lfs track "*.msi"`. Now it shows up when using `git lfs track` but the .gitattributes file looks like this:

```
਍∀⨀⸀洀猀椀∀ 昀椀氀琀攀爀㴀氀昀猀 搀椀昀昀㴀氀昀猀 洀攀爀最攀㴀氀昀猀 ⴀ琀攀砀琀ഀ਍⸪獭⁩楦瑬牥氽獦搠晩㵦晬⁳敭杲㵥晬⁳琭硥൴
```

What's going on? I want a readable working `.gitattributes` file.

Answer (score 0):

My .gitattributes file was UTF-16 somehow. Changed it to UTF-8, now everything is fine.